# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I built my assembly in debug mode and copied into GAC. But assembly is not showing in Module window.

When put breakpoint it says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Anybody have clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just something simple to try - you may have tried it already. Right click the Solution in solution explorer, click "**clean solution**", this deletes all the compiled and temporary files associated with a solution.

Do a rebuild of the solution and try to debug again.

I've also had troubles with breakpoints multiple projects in a solution - some compiled as x86, some as x64. Is this your setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put you PDB files in the GAC itself. Or, you can just try removing it from the GAC altogether, while debugging. Regardless, I think VS is looking for your symbols in the wrong place.